# "The Lions are playing the Redskins and Buffalo is playing Cleveland tonight"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> The Lions **are** playing the Redskins and Buffalo **is** playing Cleveland tonight.

For those who may not know, the Detroit Lions, Washington Redskins, Buffalo Bills and Cleveland Browns are American Football team names.

Now, I understand that the first part

> The Lions **are** playing the Redskins

in itself is grammatically correct. And that the second part

> Buffalo **is** playing Cleveland

in itself is correct.

Is the following also correct? (I know that it's accepted in conversation but I don't know if it is accepted in writing) Where I'm mixing city name and team name between each match.

> The Lions **are** playing Washington and Buffalo **is** playing the Browns

What bothers me is that even though read aloud it sounds fine to me, I find it odd that you would see a sentence that maintains tense but uses both **are** and **is** to describe it.
If this is acceptable, is the reason for it being accepted due to the "***the***" placed in front of the second part of the team name?

Comment: The verb agrees in number with its subject; the object is irrelevant.

Comment: There are posts on ELU dealing with agreement with collective nouns. Wikipedia looks at the idiosyncratic usages with sports teams , pop groups etc in plural form.

Comment: @StoneyB The verbform depends on the subject, never the object. It does not always have to agree with the singular / plural _form_ of the subject. 'The works is shutting down and the staff have not yet been told' would cause no concern (grammatically speaking) in the UK.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Quite so. Figuring out the subject's number can be tricky. In OP's examples a British sportswriter might write *Buffalo are playing the Browns*.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, they certainly would. Manchester United are playing Wolves tonight and Wolves are playing Sunderland on Saturday. So much for football. England are shortly to play in the Rugby World Cup, as are Scotland, Wales and Ireland. Today I have been watching cricket. Australia are playing England at The Oval.

Comment: @WS2 Grits is good.

Comment: @StoneyB Watts is an electrician called in to determine why the watts are reduced.

Comment: @WS2 There you go; another transatlantic divide. I would say he was called in to fix whats up.

Comment: @StoneyB So good that it's impossible to eat just one grit.

Comment: @deadrat Except the single, Platonic true grit.

Comment: @StoneyB Only in cinema and then only with John Wayne.

Comment: @deadrat Film, alas, whether Wayne or Bridges, is but a shadow, a projection upon the cavern wall of the Portisian logos.

Comment: @StoneyB True, the remake was a Bridges too far, a shadow of the original.  I'd recommend the Five Senses Cinema where at least the projection is in IMAX

Answer (score 1):

Am. English, my opinion:

Your funny hybrid sentence is correct, but I can understand if it makes you feel a little queasy, like a sentence that jumps back and forth from one language to another several times.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is referring to two versions of the same group of football players.

The Lions are playing Washington and Buffalo is playing the Browns.

"The Lions" refers to the team itself, as does "the Browns."  "Washington" and "Buffalo" refer to the city the team plays in and is not plural.  You wouldn't say "Washington are playing Buffalo."

Is this particularly American English?  Would a British speaker say "Manchester are playing Bournemouth tomorrow"?